# SharePoint List & Bing Map

Tags: google-maps

Is http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/arcgis/archive/2010/05/21/ArcGIS-Mapping-for-SharePoint.aspx for free?

Comment: Sorry, but this is really off topic here. You should try contacting Esri using the link Mike has below.

Answer (score 1):

ESRI offers some good, but potentially expensive products.  If you click the link to the product and then the pricing page you can find the details.

If this is for use on your company's intranet, then there would be a fee.
http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/mapping-sharepoint/pricing.html